Re-orderable Grid View Lags with .animation
I am trying to create a re-orderable grid view in swiftUI using a LazyVGrid. The grid is rendering a bunch of thumbnails of a presentation which contain the paths in an array. The DragRelocateDelegate handles dragging and dropping each slide, which then changes the index of the moved slide in the presentation.thumbnails array.
The issue is that the .animation on the LazyVGrid is super laggy when moving a slide through the grid. How can this be more efficient so that this animation does not lag. Thanks!
//
//  EditPresentationView.swift
//  Interactive
//
//  Created by Vikrant Gurav on 02/12/2024.
//

import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct EditPresentationView: View {
    @State var presentation: Presentation
    var saveChanges: (Presentation) -> Void
    @EnvironmentObject var mediaCacheManager: MediaCacheManager
    @State private var dragging: String?

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 175, maximum: 175)),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Spacer().frame(height: 60)
                HStack {
                    Text("Edit \(presentation.name)")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            saveChanges(presentation)
                            mediaCacheManager.mediaCache.removeAll()
                            mediaCacheManager.thumbnailCache.removeAll()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(IconButtonStyle())
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                Spacer().frame(height: 25)
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(Array(presentation.thumbnails.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, slidePath in
                            if let image = mediaCacheManager.loadImage(from: slidePath) {
                                GridItemView(image: image, index: index)
                                    .onDrag {
                                        self.dragging = slidePath
                                        return NSItemProvider(object: String(describing: index) as NSString)
                                    }
                                    .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(
                                        item: slidePath,
                                        listData: $presentation.thumbnails,
                                        slidesData: $presentation.slides,
                                        current: $dragging
                                    ))
                                    .contextMenu {
                                        Button(role: .destructive) {
                                            deleteSlide(at: index)
                                        } label : {
                                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .animation(.smooth(), value: presentation.thumbnails)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
                .overlay(
                    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black.opacity(1), Color.black.opacity(1), Color.black.opacity(0.75)]),
                                   startPoint: .top,
                                   endPoint: .bottom)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50)
                        .blur(radius: 5)
                        .offset(y: -25),
                    alignment: .top
                )
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteSlide(at index: Int) {
           guard index >= 0 && index < presentation.thumbnails.count,
                 index < presentation.slides.count else {
               return
           }
           presentation.thumbnails.remove(at: index)
           presentation.slides.remove(at: index)
       }
}

struct DragRelocateDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let item: String
    @Binding var listData: [String]
    @Binding var slidesData: [String]
    @Binding var current: String?

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        if let current = current {
            if let fromIndex = listData.firstIndex(of: current),
               let toIndex = listData.firstIndex(of: item), fromIndex != toIndex {
                listData.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet([fromIndex]), toOffset: toIndex > fromIndex ? toIndex + 1 : toIndex)
                slidesData.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet([fromIndex]), toOffset: toIndex > fromIndex ? toIndex + 1 : toIndex)
            }
        }
    }

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        self.current = nil
        return true
    }
}

struct GridItemView: View {
    var image: Image
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(maxWidth: 150, maxHeight: 150)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.25), lineWidth: 2)
                )
            Text("\(index + 1)")
                .font(.caption)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(20)
    }
    
    
}


Note unrelated, but you should not have
@State var presentation: Presentation, you pass this from the parent View
using a @Binding or a var, or you give it an initial value when you declare it.
